# GtkSourceView syntax highlighting - highlight until "=",

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gtksourceview

I have a custom SPICE (electronics) syntax highlighting for gEdit, it's working, but I would like to modify the highlighting for variables (and I don't know how to). What I have now is this:

```
<context id="variables" style-ref="string">
  <match extended="true">
    (\s[^\s&gt;&lt;&amp;(){};,=/+\-*\^]+|
    (?![({])\s*[^\s&gt;&lt;&amp;(){};,=/+\-*\^]+)
    \s*(\=)(?!(\s*\=))
  </match>
</context>
```

The parameters (variables) are defined like this:

`.param Value=3.14`

and, with the above code, "Value=" is highlighted, but I would like to omit the "=" from being coloured. I have tried `(?!\=)` on the last row, after `'s*`, plus a few combinations but... nothing.

In a more detailed way:

- the parameters are defined by a mandatory first `.param` or `.params` (this is solved)
- they cannot have spaces or any character like these -- [^\s><&(){};,=/+-*\^] -- inside their namings (solved)
- they must have at least one space before to not "mingle" with the previous characters (solved)
- the above condition has the "(" and "{" exceptions (solved)
- they can have spaces between them and "=" (solved)

Please bear in mind that I have very little knowledge about PCRE, this is probably childish-looking but I don't mind as long as it's working. What I have now is done by too many trials-and-errors.

Comment: Just to add one more condition: there cannot be two equal signs after the variable, because then it's no longer a variable to be defined. The equal signs can have spaces before/between/after, but, anyway, this condition is also solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I solved it with the help from jessevdk from #gedit on irc.gimp.org. The line

```
\s*(\=)(?!(\s*\=))
```

needs to be changed to

```
(?=(\s*\=(?!(\s*\=))))
```

Now I can update the file on https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692822 and wait some more for acceptance...